# Working out the maximum range of memory locations

Tags: cpu-architecture

Can someone help me understand this question:

A processor providing 64GB of addressable main memory such as the AMD FX8350
Which of the following is the correct maximun range of main memory locations for such a processor?

A.0x000 to 0x3FF

B.0x0 0000 TO 0x3F FFFF

C.0x000 0000 TO 0x3FF FFFF

D.0x0 0000 0000 TO 0x3F FFFF FFFF

E.0x0 000 000 000 TO 0x3F FFFF FFFF FFFF

Comment: This is a very simple homework. My experience is that when you fail such simple exercises is best to back off a bit and brush on the basic material. For example, what happen when you convert those addresses in decimal and use the Giga-binary scale?

Comment: It's not this simple in reality, the physical memory map has holes (some of which are very large) and thus for example if you had 4GB of RAM it would extend beyond 0xFFFFFFFF quite a bit.

Comment: I don't think this is a real-world example @harold, I believe it's a homework made to train the OP in conversions. When details lack It's usually a simple scenario homework :). Also, it's addressable memory, so holes don't count anyway.

Comment: I don't even know what the question is asking or what type of conversion i am suppose to be doing here

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no simple answer to this question. The microprocessor will have different [addressing modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode) and will map real memory into the virtual address space in pages, usually of 4k in size. So the virtual address space may not even be contiguous.

Comment: The  AMD FX8350 is just used as an eample this couldbe for any processor providing 64gm main memory, i'm sure its a simple calculation i just can't remember.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no such thing as "Processor providing xx memory". A processor can specify how many bits of addresses it is able to operate on. Most common cases are 32 and 64 bit. Processors with 32 bit addressing, are able to access 2^32 locations = 4GB. Processors with 64 bit addressing, theoretically, is able to address 2^64 locations. However most of them, only support 48 bits of addressing providing 256 TB of addressable space.

Now in order to make use this capabilities, you need the support of the operating system as well, i. if you have a 64 bit processor and a 32 bit OS, you can only access 32 bit addresses.